# Php laravel 5 fatalexception unexpected end of file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following code snippet to end a file in php and laravel.

```
 @extends('master')
 @section('content')
   <p>Hello World</p>  
 @endsection
```

master.blade.php file is as below

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="em">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>{{ $title }}</title>
    {{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/jquery.js') }}

 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      {{ HTML::link('/','login',array('class' => 'brand')) }}
      <ul class="nav pull-right">
        @if(Auth::user())
         <li>{{ HTML::link('logout', 'Logout') }}</li>
        @else 
        <li>{{ HTML::link('login','login') }}</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
<div class="container">

    @yield('content')
</div>
```

However, I get the following error:

```
FatalErrorException in 4d94a10943d3d038e850b4e898e794a8 line 33:
syntax error, unexpected end of file
```

What exactly is the syntax to end the file in laravel,php using the blade template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `@endif` directive. Your blade syntax needs to be:

```
@if(Auth::user())
    <li>{{ HTML::link('logout', 'Logout') }}</li>
@else 
    <li>{{ HTML::link('login','login') }}</li>
@endif
```

Without the `@endif` directive, you'll get the "unexpected end of file" error.